# Where can I take a pool of words from?

Tags: string-manipulation, text

Dear Community members,

I am thinking about an interactive machine to teach a school child to write difficult words correctly. As a first step I need a collection of words. I will select a pool of words from this collection. Then I will use the pool to make the machine.

My question is: is there a way to get the words with *Mathematica*?  A constraint is that I need German words.

Answer (score 20):

It might be overkill, but with:

`DictionaryLookup[{"German", All}]`

you get a list of every German word. To be a bit more precise, you could then narrow things with string searches, i.e. `DictionaryLookup[{"German", "a" ~~ ___ ~~ "b"}]` gets you a list of words that begin with a and end with b. [Full documentation is here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DictionaryLookup.html).

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you build your own kind of database using sources from the web and copy&past the content into a text file. Afterwards you can use the Import functionalities Mathematica offers.

A possible source I think is appropriate: (you may have to filter some words out by hand which you think could be to difficult for your student)

http://www.duden.de/schwierige-woerter

Extracting words from webpages is usually straightforward after examining the structure of the page a little bit.  Here is a concrete example:

```
page = Import["http://www.duden.de/schwierige-woerter", "XMLObject"];

Cases[page, 
 XMLElement[
   "span", {"class" -> "field-content"}, {XMLElement["a", _, {s_String}]}] :> s, Infinity]
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added some example code for extracting the words.  Please edit to your liking.

Comment: Very neat:) I never thought about handling the issue programmatically. I must admit compared to your method copy&paste is rather crude.

Comment: Actually for a simple list like this one you're right that copy-paste is much faster ... I made a small palette for these kinds of tasks a long time ago, it's [here](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php) (search for "tabular" on the page---I should update that page some day ...).  It works fine with this page and TSV paste, I just needed to filter the alphabet (A, B, C...) from the list.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please comment on the role of parameters in the operator? Just to understand, how this code works.

Answer (score 8):

If you need a more comprehensive list of German words you could download a file such as [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/germandict/files/german.7z/download), unzip it and then load it with `Import`.

The default *Mathematica* German dictionary contains 76155 words, whereas the dictionary available with the link above contains 1328614 words.

Comment: ideal for school children - make them work!

Answer (score 7):

You could use the function `DictionaryLookup`. At least at my machine, it supports German but I'm not sure whether this depends on the installation or not. Just look it up in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think it depends on installation since it grabs the data from Wolfram servers